# Change the color of action button in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to change the color of the action button from gray to orange.

```
actionButton("run","Run Analysis")
```

(This is in `server.R`.) Is it possible to change its color?

Comment: you could use http://rstudio.github.io/shinythemes/ or possibly add tags$head() (see http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/tag-glossary.html) in your ui.R file

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As @MLavoie mentioned, you can embed CSS in your shiny app using `tags$head`. Try this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML('#run{background-color:orange}'))
  ),
  actionButton("run","Run Analysis")
))
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you're unfamiliar to CSS, w3schools has really good and easy tutorials.

Comment: To add a hover-style, use something like `tags$style(HTML('#run{background-color:orange} #run:hover{background-color:red}`)).

Answer (score 120):

Below, I've made your action button look like a submit button (also adding a [font-awesome icon](https://fontawesome.com/search?m=free)):

```
actionButton("run", "Run Analysis", icon("paper-plane"), 
    style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4")
```

Comment: May be you know is there way to add style to `:hover` in this way?

Comment: How come this style argument does not work for all other inputs as well, does anyway know?

Comment: @BigDataScientist it often does actually, but much depends on the actual constructor function. And you need to use the correct labels inside.

Comment: @Batanichek In case you never found an answer: see my comment under the accepted answer by Rmlu.

Answer (score 22):

You can use boostrap colors in the `class` attribute:

```
actionButton("run","Run Analysis", class = "btn-warning")
```

These are basic colors only but really usefull for graphic standards.

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/ for more options!