# Assigning custom CSS classes to designed object via external CSS file

Tags: css, r, css-selectors, shiny

When working with a ShinyApp of the following structure:

```
.
├── server.R
├── ui.R
└── www
    └── custom.css
```

I would like to utilise the `custom.css`, which is linked to the app in the following manner:

```
tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css")
),
```

By assigning distinct classes to separate widgets.

## Files

### `ui.R`

The `ui.R` defines a number of widgets, I would like to have three sliders, two with distinct classes:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

    # Link CSS file
    tags$head(
        tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css")
    ),

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
    sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput(
            "bins",
            "Number of bins:",
            min = 1,
            max = 50,
            value = 30
        ),

        # Class call to odd class
        sliderInput(
            "binsA",
            "Number of bins (someOddClass):",
            min = 1,
            max = 50,
            value = 30
        ),

        # Class call to even more odd class
        sliderInput(
            "binsB",
            "Number of bins (someEvenMoreOddClass):",
            min = 1,
            max = 50,
            value = 30
        )
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot"))
)))
```

### `custom.css`

The `custom.css` defines the following classes:

```
.someOddClass {
 font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 font-size: 23px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #336699;
}

.someEvenMoreOddClass {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

### `server.R`

`server.R` doesn't do anything relevant in the context of this example:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')

  })

})
```

## Side notes

The working solution, derived from the discussion available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35871042/1655567) suggests including `style = ...` in the widget call. I'm not interested in this approach as I want to utilise the `custom.css` file (makes sense from the perspective of a wider workflow as the file is utilised more extensively).

The generated source:

```
  <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
    <label class="control-label" for="binsA">Number of bins (someOddClass):</label>
    <input class="js-range-slider" id="binsA" data-min="1" data-max="50" data-from="30" data-step="1" data-grid="true" data-grid-num="9.8" data-grid-snap="false" data-keyboard="true" data-keyboard-step="2.04081632653061" data-drag-interval="true" data-data-type="number" data-prettify-separator=","/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
    <label class="control-label" for="binsB">Number of bins (someEvenMoreOddClass):</label>
    <input class="js-range-slider" id="binsB" data-min="1" data-max="50" data-from="30" data-step="1" data-grid="true" data-grid-num="9.8" data-grid-snap="false" data-keyboard="true" data-keyboard-step="2.04081632653061" data-drag-interval="true" data-data-type="number" data-prettify-separator=","/>
  </div>
```

shows existence of classes for the slider:

```
<input class="js-range-slider" id="binsB" ...
```

In practice, I would like to extend it and inject another call to the classes defined in the `custom.css`. Naturally, introducing `class = ...` to the `inputSlider()`:

```
        value = 30,
        class = "someOddClass"
        (...)
    ),
```

will result in an error as the argument does not make sense in the context of the `inputSlider()`:

```
Error : unused argument (class = "someOddClass")
```

*How can I change sliderInput() call so it creates the tag referencing the desired custom class?*

Comment: Can you do it by id? or do you have many sliders per CSS class? If you can do it by `id`, in your `custom.css`, you could have `#binsA` instead of `.someOddClass` for ex. Not ideal if you have many sliders though.

Comment: @NicE Thanks for showing the interest. ID may be a fallback options but I'm using some widgets, like the [bookmark button](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html) where id is not commonly utilised, however permissible. Ideally, I would like to find a method where I could call a specific class on a given element using ID or not. Also I would like to leave `custom.css` possibly untouched but the solution you are suggestion will have to do if there is no way to just call specific class  on any element.

Comment: ok, then you can do something like `tags$div(class="someEvenMoreOddClass",sliderInput(...))` to wrap the input in a div with a class of your choice. The most flexible choice would probably be to use an `index.html` and set the classes wherever you want like [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/html-ui.html)

Comment: @NicE Thanks this would work as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your elements in `tags$div` and add a class to that `div`:

For ex:

```
tags$div(class="someEvenMoreOddClass",sliderInput(...))
```

If you want to be even more precise about where you add your class, you can use `tags$html` and paste the html output of the `sliderInput` command, then add your class where it needs to be added:

```
tags$html(HTML('
        <div class="form-group shiny-input-container someEvenMoreOddClass">
          <label class="control-label" for="bins">Number of bins:</label>
          <input class="js-range-slider" id="bins" data-min="1" data-max="50" data-from="30" data-step="1" data-grid="true" data-grid-num="9.8" data-grid-snap="false" data-keyboard="true" data-keyboard-step="2.04081632653061" data-drag-interval="true" data-data-type="number" data-prettify-separator=","/>
        </div>
'))
```

You can also go build your entire ui.R in html like [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/html-ui.html)